# Change in top right bar

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I changed from "Settings" to "About" in the top right? Im using Android 4.0 like this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEyRQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action bar menu is changed in the menu xml file. This is found in your project under res/menu and may be called something like 'main.xml'.

I'm assuming you're using the one automatically generated by eclipse. It will probably look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

The bit that says:

```
<android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

this is the bit that controls what it says there. So you need go to the 'strings.xml'  file in 'res/values' and change that string to say "About".

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

Change it to reflect the above in strings.xml and it should be sorted.